# Turn of Auto complete in Paw

Tags: paw-app

How can I turn off the auto complete option in Paw?

The UI of Paw has an auto complete option that is for me a bit agressieve.

For instance I create a new POST Request, go to the body, set it to JSON mode, and start typing property names. Since I know them by hard I want to do it fast.

However when I type something like `name` and press tab, it automatically changes this to a Dynamic Value `Variable name`. Same with typing the string value `2` with a quick tab this changes to `MD2`. When I then want to execute the request, it is not what I wanted, and it will have blancs because I did not setup the dynamic vars correctly.

Don't get me wrong I have been using Paw for a few years now and loving the app, however this part really annoys me. Especially with a large project setup with a lot of Environment variables configured.

I have tried to live with it, try to look for it and type esc instead of tab on the right times. However constantly looking if Paw would do the auto complete is just annoying and slows me down quite a bit.

Have I missed a configurable setting somewhere?

Comment: Hey Mark! Sorry for the delay in answering here. This is a known issue and has bothered us also :) We're going to release a bug fixing version shortly.